# Android: Putting Search Option in default Title bar

Tags: android, android-search

I am new in android app development and I want to put a search option on title bar on some specific activities (not every activity inside the app). How should I start this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if u start your application in api level 11 or even higher, u can learn actionbar through below link:

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html

Adding an Action View, for example, SearchView.

For another, if u want implement this function, u can see ActionBarSherlock api to make it compatiable, please follow below link:

http://actionbarsherlock.com/

Comment: The 2nd guide worked for me for api level 11+ well. But for api level 10 I had to implement a custom layout. Thanks anyway. I shall try it again when I need. :)

Comment: oh, no, you can use actionbarsherlock to make your application compatiable,  if need help, please let me know.

Comment: can I use actionbarsherlock for api level 10 ? Then I appreciate your help. And sorry for being unable to give reputation because I haven't earned sufficient Reputation.